# in Android Ndk 'malloc.h' file not found

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

i want use malloc lib when i create a new .c file and .h file  .android studio tell me 'malloc.h' file not found.
I use CMake to compile.
is my CMakeLists.txt.
I am a ndk rookie.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( 
        native-lib
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
        log-lib

        log)


target_link_libraries( 
        native-lib
        jnigraphics
        ${log-lib})
```

This is the cpp folder structure

[image]

What modification should I make?

Comment: What do you need `malloc.h` for (which specific function(s))? Can't you use `stdlib.h` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know. I need to add a .c file to `add_library` .

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    native-lib
    
    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED
    
    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    native-lib.cpp
    stackblur.c)
```